# Tab-Content Dropping a line when I don't want it to

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel with 2 tabs and different content. However, when I do a col-md-8 in tab 1, that's carryingover into tab 2, I want tab 2 to start fresh. Here's my code:

```
        <div class="col-md-12"> 
            <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Quick</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2default" data-toggle="tab">Advanced</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" value='<?php echo $value; ?>' required>
                                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
                                      </span>
                                </div><!-- /input-group -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." id="searchTerm" name="searchTerm" value='<?php echo $value; ?>' required>
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="action"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</button>
                                </span>
                            </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing anything unexpected here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/902Ep

Could you take a screenshot of the problem area?